# zombie.js-triggered AJAX requests don't complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, zombie.js

I'm trying to write unit tests with Zombie.js. My problem is that AJAX requests aren't finishing when initiated using `browser.evaluate`, even though they execute fine when included on the page with a script tag.

I have three files:

- `index.html`: the HTML page which zombie loads
- `hello.txt`: a plain text file with the contents `hello, world`
- `main.js`: a zombie.js program which loads `index.html`

`index.html` and `hello.txt` are served using the command `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8009`. (note that I'm using `dev.local`, which is a synonym for `127.0.0.1` in my hosts file)

Here is `index.html`. It makes an AJAX request to retrieve `hello.txt`. This works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js'>
  </script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $.support.cors = true;
    var doRequest = function(msg) {
      $.support.cors = true;
      return $.ajax({
        url: "http://dev.local:8009/hello.txt",
        success: function(v) { console.log("success ", msg, v); }
      });
    };
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("page loaded");                                                                                                                                                    
    doRequest('script');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's `main.js`. It navigates to `index.html` and tries to evaluate the `doRequest` function, which should cause an AJAX request. However, the request never completes, and instead times out.

```
var Browser = require("zombie");
const browser = new Browser({debug: true});
const rootURL = "http://dev.local:8009/"

browser.visit(rootURL, function(err) {                                                                                                                                             
  browser.evaluate('console.log("browser.evaluate ✔");');
  browser.evaluate('doRequest("zombie");');
});
```

Here is the log from running `DEBUG=zombie node ./main.js`:

```
  zombie Opened window http://dev.local:8009/  +0ms
  zombie GET http://dev.local:8009/ => 200 +38ms
  zombie Loaded document http://dev.local:8009/ +36ms
  zombie GET https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js => 200 +55ms
page loaded
  zombie XHR readystatechange http://dev.local:8009/hello.txt +64ms
  zombie XHR loadstart http://dev.local:8009/hello.txt +1ms
  zombie GET http://dev.local:8009/hello.txt => 200 +9ms
  zombie XHR readystatechange http://dev.local:8009/hello.txt +1ms
  zombie XHR readystatechange http://dev.local:8009/hello.txt +0ms
  zombie XHR readystatechange http://dev.local:8009/hello.txt +1ms
  zombie XHR progress http://dev.local:8009/hello.txt +0ms
success  script hello, world

  zombie XHR load http://dev.local:8009/hello.txt +2ms
  zombie XHR loadend http://dev.local:8009/hello.txt +0ms
  zombie Fired setTimeout after 0ms delay +1ms
  zombie Event loop is empty +0ms
browser.evaluate ✔
  zombie XHR readystatechange http://dev.local:8009/hello.txt +4ms
  zombie XHR loadstart http://dev.local:8009/hello.txt +0ms
  zombie GET http://dev.local:8009/hello.txt => 200 +6ms
```

Oddly, zombie seems to have actually completed the request: the final line of the log shows that a HTTP `200` response was received, but the event was never given to the handler.

Why doesn't the zombie-initiated request complete correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue with zombie.js and so i looked at the source and found the following lines:

```
// -- Event processing --

// Grabs next event from the queue, processes it and notifies all listeners.
// Keeps processing until the queue is empty or all listeners are gone. You
// only need to bootstrap this when you suspect it's not recursing.
//... more lines ...
// Is there anybody out there?
if (this.waiting === 0)
    return;
```

so no events get fired if noone is waiting you need to add `browser.wait()`

```
browser.visit(rootURL, function(err) {                                                                                                                                             
    browser.evaluate('console.log("browser.evaluate ✔");');
    browser.evaluate('doRequest("zombie");');
    browser.wait();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct. Using `wait`, you can get data that is ajaxed. Just another example to adapt by creating a function that accepts the browser as a parameter:

```
async function getAjaxedData(url, browser) {
    return browser.visit(url).wait().then(() => {
        // Do stuff
        // e.g. browswer.queryAll(selector)
    });
}
```